# How to convert multiple character variables to datetime at once?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate, readr

Trying to convert multiple character variables to datetimes. Simplified example:

```
#create df/tibble with two "datetime" columns still as character 
df=tibble(date1=c("2013-11-26 00:10:12.536","2013-11-26 23:04:32.512","2014-02-19 23:34:44.459"),
          date2=c("2013-11-26 07:06:40.720","2013-11-27 07:09:50.552","2014-02-20 08:00:03.975"))

datetimeFormat="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"

#OK: converting a single var using $
df_temp=df
df_temp$date1=as_datetime(df_temp$date1,format = datetimeFormat)

#not OK: converting a single var using indexing (presumably because df_temp[,"date1"] is still a tibble)
df_temp=df
df_temp[,"date1"]=as_datetime(df_temp[,"date1"],format = datetimeFormat)

#also not OK: converting multiple variables in one go
datetimeVars=c("date1","date2")
df_temp=df
df_temp[,datetimeVars]=as_datetime(df_temp[,datetimeVars],format = datetimeFormat)
```

How can I convert multiple character columns to datetime at once, specifically using a *variable* containing the variable names (like *datetimeVars* above)?

Some context:

- my source csv files are not uniform and contain a variable - often large - number of datetimes-to-be (in custom format as example above). I can determine which variables should become datetime from their names
- read_csv does not consistently recognize the relevant variables as datetime
- read_csv does not appear to allow setting variable type for multiple variables at once, so can't do something like: `df=read_csv("myFile.csv",col_types=cols(datetimeVars=col_datetime(format=datetimeFormat)))` I also can't specify/hardcode variable type for each relevant variable like `cols(date1=col_datetime(),date2=col_datettime, date3=...)` because the number of datetime variables isn't known ahead of time

So currently stuck at both the levels of import (read_csv) and conversion (as_datetime). Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tackling the conversion part since the import highly depends on the files and the included formats.

Convert to `date` class using `as.POSIXct` (keep in mind that the `date` class is always shown in the format printed but keeps more info in the class object - see *Reading* below).

```
library(dplyr)

datetimeVars <- c("date1", "date2")

df_date <- df %>% 
  summarise(across(all_of(datetimeVars), as.POSIXct))
df_date
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  date1               date2              
  <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 2013-11-26 00:10:12 2013-11-26 07:06:40
2 2013-11-26 23:04:32 2013-11-27 07:09:50
3 2014-02-19 23:34:44 2014-02-20 08:00:03
```

or with column names matching a starting pattern (`starts_with()`)

```
datetimeVars <- c("date")

df_date <- df %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with(datetimeVars), as.POSIXct))
df_date
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  date1               date2              
  <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 2013-11-26 00:10:12 2013-11-26 07:06:40
2 2013-11-26 23:04:32 2013-11-27 07:09:50
3 2014-02-19 23:34:44 2014-02-20 08:00:03
```

*Reading* your desired format from `date` class with `strftime`

```
df_date %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with("date"), strftime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3"))
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  date1                   date2                  
  <chr>                   <chr>                  
1 2013-11-26 00:10:12.536 2013-11-26 07:06:40.720
2 2013-11-26 23:04:32.512 2013-11-27 07:09:50.552
3 2014-02-19 23:34:44.459 2014-02-20 08:00:03.974
```

Comment: excellent! thx for pointing to across(all_of) as the "indexing" operation: wouldn't have guessed. just slightly confused this needs to be rolled into "summarise" (since we're not summarizing).

also, sticking with tidyverse and ensuring the correct format, I think your first solution is equivalent to: `summarise(df,across(all_of(datetimeVars), as_datetime, format = datetimeFormat))`?

Comment: @mrroy That's true. `summarise()` creates a new data frame which is why it's used here. You can achieve the same result with `mutate()` in your case because the output has the same variable names. Generally `mutate()` will add new columns in other scenarios.